# NSArray creating a subarray and then summing the values

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nspredicate, nsrange

I have some code that was originally written as:

```
+(double)averageOfArray:(NSArray*)array fromIndex:(int)from toIndex:(int)to{
    if (to < 0) return 0;
    if (to > array.count) return 0;
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (long i = from; i < to; i++){
        sum += [array[i] doubleValue];
    }
    return sum/(double)(to-from);
}
```

But I am trying to write it so that it's more efficient. I don't know if this will be faster or not, but one idea is to create a subarray and then calling `valueForKeyPath:@"sum.self"` like this:

```
...
NSArray *t = [array subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(from, to-from)];
double sum = [[t valueForKeyPath:@"sum.self"] doubleValue];
return sum/(double)(to-from);
```

But this is throwing an error:

> Thread 1: Exception: "[<__NSCFNumber 0xd99f8c3636814118>
>   valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant
>   for the key sum."

Looking at the debugger it shows my `NSArray *t` as `t = (__NSArrayl_Transfer *) @"500 elements"`. But when I look at an array that I've created like this `NSArray *testArray = @[@0.1, @0.2, @0.3, @0.4 @0.5, @0.6];` then that shows up as as `testArray = (__NSArrayl *) @"6 elements"`. I'm assuming that for some reason these underlying types are where the problem is.

I've tried creating a new array by doing this:

```
NSArray *t = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[array subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(from, to-from)] copyItems:YES];`
```

But that does not fix the issue. What am I failing to understand?

Comment: You're missing `@`. `@"sum.self"` should be `@"@sum.self"`.

Comment: You nailed it! Thank you. I'd been staring at this for hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Using Collection Operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-BAJEAIEE):

> When a key path contains a collection operator, any portion of the key path preceding the operator, known as the left key path, indicates the collection on which to operate relative to the receiver of the message. If you send the message directly to a collection object, such as an `NSArray` instance, the left key path may be omitted.
>
> The portion of the key path after the operator, known as the right key path, specifies the property within the collection that the operator should work on. All the collection operators except `@count` require a right key path.
>
> Operator key path format
>
> ```
> keypathToCollection.@collectionOperator.keypathToProperty
> |_________________| |_________________| |_______________|
>
>    Left key path         Operator        Right key path
> ```

- You're sending the message directly to a collection object, you can omit the left key path.
- Collection operator always starts with `@`.
- Right key path is required (except `@count`).

Because you forgot to use `@` prefix, the following code ...

```c
double sum = [[t valueForKeyPath:@"sum.self"] doubleValue];
```

... tries to get `sum` from every `NSNumber *` in the array. And then you get:

> Thread 1: Exception: "[<__NSCFNumber 0xd99f8c3636814118> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key sum."

Just add the `@` prefix to the collection operator and you'll be fine:

```c
double sum = [[t valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.self"] doubleValue];
```

Comment: Wow. A very complete answer. Thank you!